# Sort data.frame in specific order (NOT ascending/descending)

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

```
a = data.frame(x = c("fl", "kl", "po", "rt", "st"), a = runif(5), b = runif(5), c = runif(5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

reference = c("po", "rt", "fl", "st", "kl")
```

There is data.frame `a` and it should be sorted on `x` according to the `reference` vector. How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `match`:

```
match(reference, a$x)
#[1] 3 4 1 5 2

a[match(reference, a$x),]
#   x          a          b         c
#3 po 0.11479400 0.85043472 0.1972569
#4 rt 0.04886256 0.04916686 0.8341600
#1 fl 0.57528688 0.31122035 0.1204271
#5 st 0.77224495 0.29492122 0.9136916
#2 kl 0.67683487 0.87516455 0.9612954
```

A solution addressing the concern of duplicated values in the data.frame (although an example should be representative of the problem):

```
a = data.frame(x = c("fl", "kl", "po", "rt", "st", "st"), a = runif(6), 
               b = runif(6), c = runif(6), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

a[order(factor(a$x, levels = reference)),]
#   x          a            b         c
#3 po 0.43392816 0.0008970879 0.7282965
#4 rt 0.74484047 0.4237432110 0.3593475
#1 fl 0.69747570 0.0441067580 0.1477714
#5 st 0.18866673 0.3650689835 0.4940101
#6 st 0.93842498 0.4953243888 0.4318899
#2 kl 0.09158319 0.6171634013 0.8798650
```

Comment: This only works for the five rows. If you have more rows with repetitive values, it won't work.

Comment: Your updated answer is very good now, and is more efficient than my solution above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a$reference <- sapply(a$x, function(x) which(x == reference))
a[order(a$reference), ]
```

You can avoid saving into a column by doing this:

```
a[order(sapply(a$x, function(x) which(x == reference))), ]
```

It works if you have many more rows with repetitions of x values as follows:

```
a2 <- rbind(a, a)
a2[order(sapply(a2$x, function(x) which(x == reference))), ]
```

Output as shown below:

```
    x          a         b          c
3  po 0.35188864 0.9611048 0.47784538
8  po 0.35188864 0.9611048 0.47784538
4  rt 0.40894400 0.7283944 0.56025326
9  rt 0.40894400 0.7283944 0.56025326
1  fl 0.04766363 0.9188573 0.05284394
6  fl 0.04766363 0.9188573 0.05284394
5  st 0.82095132 0.6863751 0.69826159
10 st 0.82095132 0.6863751 0.69826159
2  kl 0.70085309 0.2825283 0.39522013
7  kl 0.70085309 0.2825283 0.39522013
```

Comment: Just be warned that looping like that is inefficient and a problem with large data.frames.

Comment: `a[order(match(a$x,reference)),]`